# No video output from VGA card?

Tags: video, graphics-card, vga

My test machine (a Dell Optiplex 380 mini-tower, Win7) has stopped producing VGA output from the intergrated, on-board video adapter. The monitor always shows warning message "No signal".

I've tried:

- swapped monitor and cable with known-good ones
- added a VGA card from eBay (PCI)
- added a VGA card from eBay (PCIe)

All with same result.
I think it's booting Ok judging by the drive lights and sounds.
**Could this be conflict with (dead) integrated VGA?

Any other suggestions on what to try?**

Comment: If it was you would have seen output from the dGPU when it was installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a failed motherboard. After swapping all peripherals to an identical model system, all was good.

Answer (score 2):

- Try different VGA cable.
- Try different monitor.
- Do you have a graphics card installed?  Remove it and see if that resets.  This system has a BIOS option that controls which video device to prefer on boot and it and may be set to the graphics card.
- This machine was probably manufactured around or before 2010.  It's possible but unlikely this system was affected by [capacitor plague](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague) and may have one or more swollen or busted capacitors.  This requires resoldering new caps or replacing the motherboard.

Comment: Lawrence: Tried swapping monitor and cable - no joy.  Until problem, system had only an integrated video adapter. Can't check BIOS cause I have no display. Changing caps on motherboard? LOL.